# Why this calculating code is not executing properly?

Tags: c++, calculator, execution

I am new in C++ and I want to make a mini calculator at very low level which can calculate Electric bill using techniques of **Data Structures**. It is menu based program which can take the appliance and hours per day from user. I am using a structure and two stacks, one can store the user choice for appliance and the other will store the consumed hours per day.

```
    #include<iostream>
const int size=20;
struct bill
{
    float arr[size];
    int top;
}app,hrs;

void push(bill *ps, float x);
float pop(bill *ps);
float calculation(bill *app , bill *hrs);

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float hours=0.0, result=0.0;
    int c=1 , choice=0;
    app.top=-1;
    hrs.top=-1;

        cout<<"***********APPLIANCES******WATTS************\n";
        cout<<"1.Color TV\t150W\n";
        cout<<"2.Light Bulb\t60W\n";
        cout<<"3.Celling Fan\t50W\n";
        cout<<"4.Cloth dryer\t2500W\n";
        cout<<"5.Coffee Maker\t1100W\n";
        cout<<"6.Desktop Computer\t275W\n";
        cout<<"7.Electric Heater\t2500W\n";
        cout<<"8.Electric Kettle\t2100W\n";
        cout<<"9.Food Blender\t350W\n";
        cout<<"10.Refrigerator\t275W\n";
        cout<<"11.Hair Dryer\t2150W\n";
        cout<<"12.Air Conditioner\t2500W\n";
        cout<<"13.Iron\t1000W\n";
        cout<<"14.Laptop\t75W\n";
        cout<<"15.LED LightBulb\t8.5W\n";
        cout<<"16.Microwave\t1150W\n";
        cout<<"17.Oven\t2150W\n";
        cout<<"18.Smart Phone charger\t5.5W\n";
        cout<<"19.Vacuum Cleaner\t450W\n";
        cout<<"20.Washing Machine\t500W\n";


        while(c!=0)
        {
            cout<<"Enter 0 for exit and 1 to continue";
            cin>>c;
            if(c==0)
            break;
            else if(c==1)
            {
            cout<<"Enter your choice ";
            cin>>choice;
                push(&app, choice); 
        cout<<"Enter hours/per day used";
            cin>>hours;
            push(&hrs, hours);
        }
        else cout<<"Invalid input"; 
        }
        result=calculation(&app, &hrs);
        cout<<"Total Electricity Bill is : "<<result;
    return 0;
}

float calculation(bill *a, bill *h)
{
    float units=0.0, kWh=0.0, temp=0.0, cost=0.0;
    float w=0.0,total_w=0.0, total_h=0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    if(temp=pop(&app) == 1)
    w=150;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 2)
    w=60;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 3)
    w=50;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 4)
    w=2500;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 5)
    w=1100;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 6)
    w=275;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 7)
    w=2500;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 8)
    w=2100;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 9)
    w=350;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 10)
    w=275;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 11)
    w=2150;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 12)
    w=2500;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 13)
    w=1000;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 14)
    w=75;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 15)
    w=8.5;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 16)
    w=1150;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 17)
    w=2150;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 18)
    w=5.5;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 19)
    w=450;
    else if(temp=pop(&app) == 20)
    w=500;
    else 
    cout<<"Invalid Input";
    total_w=total_w+w;
    total_h=total_h+pop(&hrs);
}
kWh=total_w*total_h*30;
units=kWh/1000;
cost=units*9;
return cost;
}

void push(bill *ps, float x)
{
    if(ps->top!=size-1)
    {
        ps->top=ps->top+1;
        ps->arr[ps->top]=x;
    }
}

float pop(bill *ps)
{
        return ps->arr[ps->top--];
}
```

It can create a run time error and not calculating right

[image]

Whenever we press 0 to exit than it gives wrong output
can anobody help so I can get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems in your code first is the `for` loop in your `calculation` function. It must be from 0 to top not size since size must be containing raw values on positions you don't initialize. Consider this you have an array of 5, let say in the following manner:

```
int a[5];
a[0]=2;
a[1]=4;
```

now you say add all location and give result like follows:

```
result=a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3]+a[4];
```

location 0 and 1 have 2 and 4 respectively but rest have garbage.

second problem in your code is the `pop` function call in repeated if statement. for that you can do in start of loop statements:

```
top=pop(a);
```

`a` will be passed not `app` since you passed app in a.

Lastly add one more statement as check statement or safe control `w=0;` since in your else invalid is printing and w is still having its previous value thus not giving correct output.

also even if a is having invalid option your hours must be included in total hours thus to stop that happening you must use a variable h and must give it value if input is valid else it must be zero. Therefore your code will look like:

```
 float calculation(bill *a, bill *h)
 {
     float units=0.0, kWh=0.0, temp=0.0, cost=0.0;
     float w=0.0,total_w=0.0, total_h=0.0,hr=0.0;
     for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
         temp=pop(a);
         w=0.0;
         hr=pop(h);
         if(temp == 1)
             w=150;
         else if(temp == 2)
             w=60;
         else if(temp == 3)
             w=50;
         else if(temp == 4)
             w=2500;
         else if(temp == 5)
             w=1100;
         else if(temp == 6)
             w=275;
         else if(temp == 7)
             w=2500;
         else if(temp == 8)
             w=2100;
         else if(temp == 9)
             w=350;
         else if(temp == 10)
             w=275;
         else if(temp == 11)
             w=2150;
         else if(temp == 12)
             w=2500;
         else if(temp == 13)
             w=1000;
         else if(temp == 14)
             w=75;
         else if(temp == 15)
             w=8.5;
         else if(temp == 16)
             w=1150;
         else if(temp == 17)
             w=2150;
         else if(temp == 18)
             w=5.5;
         else if(temp == 19)
             w=450;
         else if(temp == 20)
             w=500;
         else{
             cout<<"Invalid Input";
             hr=0;
         }
         total_w=total_w+w;
         total_h=total_h+hr;
      }
      kWh=total_w*total_h*30;
      units=kWh/1000;
      cost=units*9;
      return cost;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `calculation` function, ***each*** `if` will call `pop`. Unless you want to call `pop` possibly multiple times in a row, then call it *once* and store the result in a variable that you use for your check.

I also suggest you read about the `switch` statement, as it will make your code cleaner.

Another problem is that the an expression like (for example) `temp=pop(&app) == 2` is equal to `temp=(pop(&app) == 2)` due to [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). That means you assign the result of the comparison `pop(&app) == 2` to `temp`, which will make `temp` either `1` (if the comparison is `true`) or `0` (if it's `false`). Since you (in your current code) doesn't use `temp` it doesn't matter, but it's something you need to keep in mind for the future.